# using 2 canvas on same page

Tags: html

i have 2 canvas defined:

the first canvas:

```
<canvas id="viewport" style="float: right" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

and some code in JavaScript

the second canvas:

```
<canvas id="viewport2" style="float: left" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

and some code in javascript

my problem is that i have a split screen but only the second canvas is the one that is responding while the first one does nothing.
i thought maybe i need to register  both canvases somewhere but nothing worked.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to have two or more canvases, and you can even copy data from one to the other using JavaScript as a bridge. To draw on two different canvases, you need to have two seperate canvas contexts.

[Example code](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/yeQvn/).